# recognize which radio button is checked using enum as value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, enums, radio-button

I'm struggling with WinForms. I have a `GroupBox` which wraps three `RadioButton`s. I added them using the design view and inside the constructor I tag every button to corresponding enum value like

```
public MyApp()
{
   radioBtnBasic.Tag = UserChoiceEnum.Basic;
   radioBtnLite.Tag = UserChoiceEnum.Lite;
   radioBtnStandard.Tag = UserChoiceEnum.Standard;
}
```

Inside my class I have property property of type `Dictionary` which uses this enum as a key, so I want when the user clicks on winform button to recognize which radio button is checked and to assign to that dictionary.

I've found how to fetch checked option

```
var choice = grpBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked);
```

Do I need to use switch statement to recognize which Enum is checked or is there some better way?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `Tag` you can simply get it back whenever you need. Note that you need to cast it to original type. Something like:

```
var choiceAsEnum = (UserChoiceEnum)choice.Tag;
```

Answer (score 6):

You get the UserChoiceEnum by:

```
RadioButton choice = grpBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked);
UserChoiceEnum userChoice = (UserChoiceEnum)choice.Tag;
```

Comment: The flip side of setting the one radio button to checked based on the user's choice is:

`grpBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x.Tag == usersChoice).Checked = true;`

Answer (score 0):

created enum :

```
public enum SearchType
{
    ReferenceData = 0,
    Trade = 1,
}
```

Then use `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `radioGroup` control.

```
private void RadioTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (this.RadioTypes.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
      SearchType n = (SearchType)this.RadioTypes.SelectedIndex;

      switch (n)
      {
           case SearchType.ReferenceData:
           break;

           case SearchType.Trade:
           break;
      }
}
```